# Load data from api before load view

Tags: angular, typescript

I got simple accordion:

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of showDirNames | async | filter: name; let i = index;">
   <button class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordion($event, i, item.name)"> {{item.name}} </button>
   <div class="panel" hide="!item.isActive">
      <p *ngFor="let child of showFilesNames | async | filter: name"> {{child.name}} </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
    toggleAccordion(event, index, item) {
      this.activeIndex = index;
      var element = event.target;
      
      if(element.classList.toggle("active")){
        this.showFiles(item);
      }

      if(this.element[index].isActive) {
        this.element[index].isActive = false;
      } else {
        this.element[index].isActive = true;
      }
      var panel = element.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
  }
```

And there is how I get data

```
showFiles(filename: string) 
{
    this.showFilesNames = this.uploadService.getFiles(filename);
    this.showFilesNames.forEach(element => {});
}
```

How it should looks? I want to click header of my accordion it gaves me title then this title is sending to my backend then backend giving me filenames.
The problem is that my view is loaded before data is here.

Comment: You're using `async` pipe with `this.showFilesNames` in the template which suggest it's an observable. But then you also attempt `forEach` on it that theoretically wouldn't work?

Comment: it is Observable, without forEach i can't get data.

Comment: You can give your list a default empty array `showFilesNames:MyFile[] = []`. From your service return  `Observable<MyFile[]>` and subscribe to it in your component `this.uploadService.getFiles(filename).subscribe((myFiles:MyFile[])=>{ this.showFilesNames = myFiles});`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `<ng-container *ngIf="showFileNames | async as fileNames">` it will wait till variable has data. then on loop `<p *ngFor="let fileName of fileNames | filter : name>"`. with this you can achieve what you want i think.

Comment: when I do like this I got error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: `var panel = element.nextElementSibling;` this one here is null. since the method execution started before nextElementSibling is loaded. and until the async pipe done its job it will be null until it finishes. you may wanna move that part in to shown or active like event. so it will work as expected once data loaded

Comment: looking at your code again, did you put `<div class="panel" >` into `<ng-container>` ? if so, don't. that's the part causing null error.

Comment: Yes now class="panel" is inside <ng-container> I see in console that is in html <button> and .ts  var panel = element.nextElementSibling; if (panel.style.maxHeight) {

Comment: ng container should be inside of class=panel part.

Comment: Should be: <div class="panel"> then <ng-container *ngIf..> then <p> yes?

Comment: yeah exactly. with that ngif fetches data, and <p> is not being rendered until variable has actual value.

Comment: ok now there is no null but nothing shows inside <p>

Comment: in console is: zone-evergreen.js:2845 XHR finished loading: GET

Comment: You can use f12 menu to check data is loaded inside that <p>. maybe the height not rendering normally, or maybe data not loaded either, but this is the approach you should use for let it wait for data before rendering element.

Comment: Hmm <p> is not rednering. so if it looks like no data here.

Comment: I fixed my service and now it isn't async I see correct data in my console but <p> isn't rendered.. If i delete <ng-container> I got correct results but still must open close and open

Comment: if <p> is rendered I see that height is 0px that I can't see anything